# Caesar Cipher Wrapping

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to make a caesar cipher, but I'm not sure how to wrap it. Apart from the wrapping, it is all correct. I also want to keep special characters as it is, without changing them.

Code below:

```
int main()
{
    char message[100], ch;
int i, key;

char *p = message;

cout << "Encrypted message: " << message;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code only handle positive key (the `if ch>` guard), but you don't handle negative key

Comment: It works with both

Comment: Sigh, it *doesn't* handle it. Your code only add the `key` to the `ch`, then check if the resulting sum is larger than 'Z' or 'z'. But if the key is negative, there exist a possibility of the resulting sum to be lower than 'A' or 'a', which you *don't* handle

Comment: Like @Martheen said, if you look at your output it is the letters c, b and a that don't work because subtracting 3 doesn't wrap around.  You do check for wrap around with the `if (ch > 'Z')` statements - why don't you check for `if (ch < 'A')` ?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/Bke7ul-4wv

Comment: Thats what im asking for, how would it be done?

Comment: If you already know how to handle > 'Z', why don't you know how to handle < 'A'?

Answer (score 1):

To wrap it around, you can treat the characters that need to wrap around as special cases:

```
if (message[i] < 'A') message[i] += 'Z' - 'A' + 1; //Wrap back to end of alphabet
if (message[i] > 'Z') message[i] -= 'Z' - 'A' + 1; //Wrap forward to start of alphabet
```

For that code, be sure that you only apply this to letters 'A' to 'Z', or punctuation plus lower case letters will be messed up

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how to wrap it.

Code already wraps for select positive `key`.  Good start.

Not only should addition of the key to the letter wrap, it is good to prevent overflow in that addition.  As is, `key` can have any `int` value `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`.  Let us start by taming the `key`.

Consider reducing the range of the key to [0-25].

```
cin >> key;
key = key%26;           // Key now [-25...25]
if (key < 0) key += 26; // Key now [ 0 ...25]
....
```

To avoid intermediate values outside `char` range with `ch = ch + key`, use:

```
// char ch;
int ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this question are the potential overflows. So, we need to deal with that.

Then we need to understand what decryption means. If encryption will shift everthing one to the right, decryption will shift it back to left again.

- So, with "def" and key=1, the encrpyted string will be "efg".
- And decrpytion with key=1, will shift it to left again. Result: "def"

We can observe that we simply need to shift by -1, so the negative of the key.

So, basically encryption and decryption can be done with the same routine. We just need to invert the keys.

Let us look now at the overflow problematic. For the moment we will start with uppercase characters only. Characters have an associated code. For example, in ASCII, the letter 'A' is encoded with 65, 'B' with 66 and so on. Because we do not want to calculate with such number, we normalize them. We simply subtract 'A' from each character. Then

- 'A' - 'A' = 0
- 'B' - 'A' = 1
- 'C' - 'A' = 2
- 'D' - 'A' = 3

You see the pattern. If we want to encrypt now the letter 'C' with key 3, we can do the following.

'C' - 'A' + 3 = 5  Then we add again 'A' to get back the letter and we will get 5 + 'A' = 'F'

That is the whole magic.

But what to do with an overflow, beyond 'Z'. This can be handled by a simple modulo division.

Let us look at 'Z' + 1. We do 'Z' - 'A' = 25, then +1 = 26 and now modulo 26 = 0 then plus 'A' will be 'A'

And so on and so on. The resulting Formula is: (c-'A'+key)%26+'A'

Next, what with negative keys? This is also simple. Assume an 'A' and key=-1

Result will be a 'Z'. But this is the same as shifting 25 to the right. So, we can simply convert a negative key to a psoitive shift. The simple statement will be:

```
if (key < 0)  key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;
```

And then we can call our tranformation function with a simple Lambda. One function for encryption and decrytion. Just with an inverted key.

And with the above formular, there is even no need to check for a negative values. It will work for positive and negative values.

So, `key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;` will always work.

---

Some extended information, if you work with ASCII character representation. Please have a look at any ASCII table. You will see that any uppercase and lowercase character differ by 32. Or, if you look in binary:

```
char  dez  bin           char  dez  bin
'A'   65   0100 0001     'a'   97   0110 0001 
'B'   66   0100 0010     'b'   98   0110 0010 
'C'   67   0100 0011     'b'   99   0110 0011 
 . . .
```

So, if you already know that a character is alpha, then teh only difference between upper- and lowercase is bit number 5. If we want to know, if `char`  is lowercase, we can get this by masking this bit. `c & 0b0010 0000` that is equal to `c & 32` or `c & 0x20`.

If we want to operater on either uppercase or lowercase characters, the we can mask the "case" away. With `c & 0b00011111` or `c & 31` or `c & 0x1F` we will get always equivalents for uppercase charcters, already normalized to start with one.

```
char  dez  bin        Masking         char  dez  bin         Masking
'A'   65   0100 0001  & 0x1b = 1      'a'   97   0110 0001   & 0x1b = 1
'B'   66   0100 0010  & 0x1b = 2      'b'   98   0110 0010   & 0x1b = 2
'C'   67   0100 0011  & 0x1b = 3      'b'   99   0110 0011   & 0x1b = 3
 . . .
```

So, if we use an alpha character, mask it, and subtract 1, then we get as a result 0..25 for any upper- or lowercase character.

---

Additionally, I would like tor repeat the key handling. Positive keys will encrypt a string, negative keys will decrypt a string. But, as said above, negative keys can be transormed into positive ones. Example:

```
Shifting by  -1  is same as shifting by  +25
Shifting by  -2  is same as shifting by  +24
Shifting by  -3  is same as shifting by  +23
Shifting by  -4  is same as shifting by  +22
```

So,it is very obvious that we can calculate an always positive key by: `26 + key`. For negative keys, this will give us the above offsets.

And for positve keys, we would have an overflow over 26, which we can elimiate by a modulo 26 division:

```
'A'-->  0 + 26 = 26    26 % 26 = 0 
'B'-->  1 + 26 = 27    27 % 26 = 1 
'C'-->  2 + 26 = 28    28 % 26 = 2 
'D'-->  3 + 26 = 29    29 % 26 = 3
```

--> `(c + key) % 26` will eliminate overflows and result in the correct new en/decryptd character.

And, if we combine this with the bove wisdom for negative keys, we can write: `((26+(key%26))%26)` which will work for all positive and negative keys.

Combining that with that masking, could give us the following program:

```
const char potentialLowerCaseIndicator = c & 0x20;
const char upperOrLower = c & 0x1F;
const char normalized = upperOrLower - 1;
const int withOffset =  normalized + ((26+(key%26))%26);
const int withOverflowCompensation = withOffset % 26;
const char newUpperCaseCharacter = (char)withOverflowCompensation + 'A';
const char result = newUpperCaseCharacter | (potentialLowerCaseIndicator );
```

Of course, all the above many statements can be converted into one Lambda:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

// Simple function for Caesar encyption/decyption
std::string caesar(const std::string& in, int key) {
    std::string res(in.size(), ' ');
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), [&](char c) {return std::isalpha(c) ? (char)((((c & 31) - 1 + ((26 + (key % 26)) % 26)) % 26 + 65) | (c & 32)) : c; });
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::string test{ "aBcDeF xYzZ" };
    std::cout << caesar(test, 5);
}
```

---

The last function can also be made more verbose:

```
std::string caesar1(const std::string& in, int key) {
    std::string res(in.size(), ' ');

    auto convert = [&](const char c) -> char {
        char result = c;
        if (std::isalpha(c)) {

            // Handling of a negative key (Shift to left). Key will be converted to positive value
            if (key < 0) {
                // limit the key to 0,-1,...,-25
                key = key % 26;
                // Key was negative: Now we have someting between 0 and 26
                key = 26 + key;
            };

            // Check and remember if the original character was lower case
            const bool originalIsLower = std::islower(c);

            // We want towork with uppercase only
            const char upperCaseChar = (char)std::toupper(c);

            // But, we want to start with 0 and not with 'A' (65)
            const int normalized = upperCaseChar - 'A';

            // Now add the key
            const int shifted = normalized + key;

            // Addition result maybe bigger then 25, so overflow. Cap it
            const int capped = shifted % 26;

            // Get back a character
            const char convertedUppcase = (char)capped + 'A';

            // And set back the original case
            result = originalIsLower ? (char)std::tolower(convertedUppcase) : convertedUppcase;
        }
        return result;
    };
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), convert);
    return res;
}
```